# Adding choices to check box in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add new options in a checkbox on Google forms.
I am trying to have as many checkboxes as I do files to select from.

```
function listFilesInFolder() {  
  var folderName = "Box A";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('some id');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var list = []; 
  list.push(['Name','ID','Size']);

  var files = folder.getFiles(); 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    //spread sheet info if needed
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(), file.getId(), file.getSize())
    list.push(row);

    var name = file.getName();
    AddToDropDown(name);
    console.log(name)
  }
}

function AddToDropDown(name) {
  var form = FormApp.openById('some id');
  var items = form.getItems();
  var ImageSelection = items[7].asCheckboxItem();
  ImageSelection.setChoices([
    ImageSelection.createChoice(ImageSelection.getChoices().toString()),
    ImageSelection.createChoice(name),
  ])    
}
```

Ive tried it this way and as well as

```
function AddToDropDown(name) {
  var form = FormApp.openById('some id');
  var items = form.getItems();
  var ImageSelection = items[7].asCheckboxItem();
  ImageSelection.createChoice(name);   
}
```

Neither seem to work. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to add the filenames retrieved from a folder as checkboxes.
- You want to give each filename to each checkbox.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, your script was modified.

#### Flow of this modified script:

1. Retrieve filenames and put them to an array.
2. Create "Choice" objects using `createChoice()` with the retrieved filenames.
3. Set the "Choice" objects using `setChoices()`.

#### Modified script:

```
function addfileselect() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1--5CnFK5DtptuO1bUu6MsA9oTknr-Fw2');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var names = [];
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    names.push(file.getName());
  }
  var form = FormApp.openById('1gcktQP5bKxCtAvtlgz4d9x7zI6M4koRmZkkjgefswIg');
  var items = form.getItems();
  var ImageSelection = items[7].asCheckboxItem();
  var choices = ImageSelection.getChoices();
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var choice = ImageSelection.createChoice(names[i]);
    choices.push(choice);
  }
  ImageSelection.setChoices(choices);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, if there are the existing checkboxes, the checkboxes of filenames are added. If you want to added only the checkboxes of the retrieved filenames, please replace `var choices = ImageSelection.getChoices();` to `var choices = [];`.
- It might occur an error when the number of added checkboxes is large.

#### References:

- [createChoice()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createChoice(String))
- [setChoices()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setchoiceschoices)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: No, you were right. I fixed it on my own. I'll post an answer of my own for anyone else that comes by!

Comment: @Cai Martin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

How i solved it

````
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1--5CnFK5DtptuO1bUu6MsA9oTknr-Fw2');
  contents = folder.getFiles();
  var list = [];

  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()){

    file = files.next();

    list.push(file.getName());

    var name = file.getName();


    //console.log(name)
  }
     AddToDropDown(list);



 }


function AddToDropDown(row) {
   console.log(row.length)
   var form = FormApp.openById('1gcktQP5bKxCtAvtlgz4d9x7zI6M4koRmZkkjgefswIg');
   var items = form.getItems();
   var ImageSelection = items[0].asCheckboxItem();   
   ImageSelection.setChoiceValues(row.sort());


}```
````